# update multiple documents in solr each document need to update specify fields

Tags: solr, solr4

I need to update the multiple solr documents, each document should need to update specified fields only. i tried the bottom format,it's throwing error

ex:

```
[{"add":{"doc":{"cityId":{"set":1},"id":1}}},
{"add":{"doc":{"cityId":{"set":1},"id":10}}}]
```

Error:

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":0},"error":{"msg":"Error parsing JSON field value. Unexpected OBJECT_START","code":400}}
```

how to resolve this

Comment: hey did you check out my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
Error parsing JSON field value. Unexpected OBJECT_START
```

This occurs because you are trying to pass `Array` where solr expected a `list`.

From the documentation of [Atomic updates](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON#Solr_4.0_Example) ; checkout the

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
{
 "add": {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"} },
 "add": {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"} }
}'
```